# “Is there function for finding the sum of column values in DataGridView upon mouse pointer selection ?”

Tags: vb.net

Can I calculate sum of selected cells value of columns in DataGridView as soon as I select them by dragging mouse on to them.

I tried the following code but it didn't worked for me.

```
`Private Sub grid1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grid1.SelectionChanged

Try
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid1.SelectedRows
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells("Item Rate").Value)
           Next
                       txtCr.TextboxValue = sum.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. What have you tried, what issues are you encountering, and which language are you working in? (you've tagged two different languages for some reason). I'd also recommend reading [ask], and taking the Stack Overflow [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: I have a gridview having some financial data and I want to calculate sum of column values as soon as I select them by mouse pointer just like autosum in Excel. I am working with Vb in windows programming

Comment: In the `SelectionChanged` event, do something like `double sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) { sum += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Your Column Name or Index"].Value); }`. Add more cells if needed, of course.

Comment: Thanks Jimi I will try

Comment: Hey Jimi I tried like this  Private Sub grid1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grid1.SelectionChanged
        Try
            Dim sum As Double = 0
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid1.SelectedRows
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells("Item Rate").Value)
                txtCr.TextboxValue = sum.ToString()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: but it didn't worked

Comment: Move `txtCr.TextboxValue = sum.ToString()` outside the loop. *didn't work* doesn't mean anything. You need to specify what's different from the expected output. Also, note that this code supposes that you're selecting Rows, not Cells or Columns.

Comment: Thanks Jimi for the corrections but actually there is a problem then for me in this code because I want sum of selected cells

Comment: Then, change the code to include only `SelectedCells`, setting the DGV's `SelectionMode = CellSelect`: `foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells) { if (cell.ColumnIndex == [Some Index]) { sum +=  convert.ToDouble(cell.Value); } }`. Handle the appropriate Cells indexes.

Comment: Thanks Jimi for Your valuable suggestions and guidance .. It Worked for me .. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All Thanks to Jimi**

```
 Private Sub grid1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grid1.SelectionChanged
    Try
        Dim SUM As Double = 0
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In grid1.SelectedCells
            If cell.ColumnIndex() Then
                SUM += Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next
        txtCr.TextboxValue = SUM.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class